# How to automaticly disconnect all terminal server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, terminal

I have 4 terminal servers in a cluster environment.
I logged in a server and the RAM is at 100% percent. When I look there is 54 active session.

I think one of the issue here is that there are many active session for users that worked yesterday but not today.

I though it may be a good idea to run a script on the servers that will force everyone to log off at 11:00 PM where there is no one at work.

Each servers has 32GB of RAM and each has Windows Server 2008 R2 installed

1. Is it a good idea to remove all active sessions once a day?
2. How can I automate a process that will log off everyone? is there a .bat/script file that does this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Automatically logging everyone off at a set time is a bad idea - what happens when that super important project is due in the morning and everyone is burning the midnight oil?

What you can, and should, do is set it to log off disconnected sessions after a set amount of time.  On my terminal server, that's set to 2 hours - so it won't end their session when they go to lunch, but will by the end of the day.  If they are still connected they can stay on as long as they want.

This can be setup in active directory on a per-user basis if people all need to have different settings.  In a user's properties, on the Sessions Tab, set "End a disconnected session" to whatever value you want.  The advantage of doing it this way is that you can set different restrictions for different people - maybe you never want to kick out people in the IT department or any of the executive, but want to end the sessions for everyone else.

Of course, setting it for every user might be troublesome.  In that case, you can set it in Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration.  Go to the properties for your connection, and on the Sessions tab, click "Override user settings", then choose a value "End a disconnected session".  In a clustered environment you might have to do that for each server.

In both places there are also settings for Active and Idle session limits.  These apply if the user is still connected - so you can kick people off if they keep the connection open but haven't used it for an hour.

Comment: thank you. I have added the configuration that you mentioned. end disconnected session after 2 hours and idle session after 6 hours. Is there any other useful options I should consider to make the cluster environment work better?

Comment: @Mike What's your cluster's current configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I do it the mean way.  I have a scheduled reboot of the server at ~2:00 AM. A reboot is a simple way to logoff everyone, and if it is scheduled and staff are informed they can probably handle a quick save/relogin after a few minutes in my org.  Since you have 4 servers you can stagger the exact time between the servers, so a person can simply logout, and login to a new server immediately if they happen to be burning the midnight oil.

It is also useful to do this because you can trigger any of your software updates, installs and other maintenance to happen during this reboot window.